# Leaving dispatchGroup with DEFER cause a crash

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have an rest Api async method, so use dispatch group:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup.enter()
Task.do { result in
   defer { dispatchGroup.leave() }
    //...
}
```

this make a crash `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

But

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup.enter()
Task.do { result in
    //...
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}
```

don't crash. Why?

Comment: write complete function please

Comment: Because you're not showing all your code? You're not showing where is your `wait`, which I can guess is before your `return`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point 1 is : defer is called when scope of your function ends ...

Point 2 is : dispatchGroup enter should be equal to leaves otherwise your application will crash

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found a problem: there was an extra `.leave()` that caused a crash :)